# Can a single PKI be associated with multiple Certificate policies?

Tags: x509, pki

I have a internal PKI which issues certificates for two types of end entities. First is a group of IoT devices and second is for few web applications. Subject name of the former will be X.500 DN, whereas the later contains dns address of the web application. How does an application (Relying party) validates the use(IoT device or Web application) of the target certificate? One way is to use *initial-permitted-subtrees* (refer [RFC5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280)) with empty name types. Other way i thought is to create two different policies for the two certificates types and *user-initial-policy-set* as a filter. But is it valid to have two different policies for one PKI? Which of the above two ways is more meaningful? Are there any efficient methods apart from this?

Comment: You can have as much certificate policies in single PKI/CA as you need. There is no such restrictions.

Comment: How do you propose to enforce any constraints on your web application certificates from the relying party's ( assuming it's a browser, of course) point of view?  There are no options to set either in browsers - they trust everything that chains to any of the multitude of certificates in their trust-anchor store. In such cases, your only option is to have separate certificate chains (Roots) for browser based and non-browser based use cases and try and enforce the constraints in the non-browser relying parties - assuming you have control over the development of those.